# The video preview on Blender is suddenly just a still image. How do I make it actually show a preview of the video?

Tags: edit-mode, video

Sorry if my question seems a bit newbish.[image: Blender Preview thingy]

But basically, this part that shows the video preview doesn't move at all.  It's just showing this picture, even though the little Mega Man screen in the bottom left is a video.  It's just stuck there on the preview.  How do I make it actually show a preview of the video?

Again, sorry if the question is obvious.  I'm new to Blender and desperately trying to make sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the video has not yet been rendered, and you only want to play the preview then you will press  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> . If it has been rendered, then you will use  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>F11</kbd>. I see that you're in the *uv/image editor* also, switch to *3D view* to see your preview. You can do this quickly by changing windows with the menu on the far left of the header on the bottom of the window.[image]

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark by the up/ down arrows next to the questions so that future users can reference it upon running into same or similar issues.